# renames colnames with pattern matching

Tags: regex, r

How to renames the colnames by pattern matching ; only keeping the strings which starts with "B" from column 2 to 4

colnames(j)

```
      "ensembl_gene_id"  "Sample_3605_1_B1_1321584_RC" "Sample_3605_2_B2_1321584_Eso" "Sample_3605_5_B14_1326370_RC" "Sample_3605_8_B19_1326383_RC"  "chromosome_name"  "start_position"  "end_position"
```

expected output

```
  "ensembl_gene_id"  "B1"  "B2" "B14"  "B19" "chromosome_name" "start_position"                  "end_position"
```

i tried

```
j[2:4] <- gsub(pattern = "^Sample_3605_[[:digit:]]","",j[2:4])
```

Comment: `colnames(j) <- gsub(".*?_(B[^_]*).*", "\\1", colnames(j))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
j[2:4] <- gsub(pattern = "^Sample_3605_[[:digit:]]_(B[^_]*).*","\\1",j[2:4])
```

Comment: Karthik, could you please explain the wildcard used here

Answer (score 1):

and of course the `stringr` solution

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(colnames(j)[2:4], 'B[0-9]+')
```